# Beanshell - using arraylist

Tags: java, javascript, beanshell

I am using beanshell and i want to use arraylist

My code -

```
import java.util.*; 

List test= new ArrayList();
test.add("Last Name");
```

But I am getting following exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: BeanShell script error:Typed variable declaration : 
Attempt to resolve method: add() on undefined variable or class name: test: at Line: 206
```

Any idea what is causing the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I tested the code in BeanShell itself, it works. why the exception message contains `org.apache.bsf.BSFException`

Comment: I am using Liquid Office its a HP product. We use beanshell and javascript. Runs it tomact. May be thats why ?

Answer (score 3):

Try `ArrayList test = new ArrayList();`
That worked fine for me.
Guess that the BeanShell doesn't work with polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the type of the ArrayList.  Here, you would do it like this:

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: I have tried that. Doesnt work. Gives me Syntax Error at '<' :(

Comment: So is this in Java or Javascript?

Comment: its beanshell - mentioned in title and question

Comment: current version (2.0b4) of BeanShell does not support Java 1.5 generic syntax

Comment: thats right generics are not supported. But i am not sure whats wrong in my code.